# Removing specific groups in R in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to remove the groups from my dataset using data.table. I already have a vector containing all the groups that I want to keep:

```
group_vector <- c(1001, 2800, 3230, 4600)
```

This is my current dataframe:

```
structure(list(group = c(1001, 2025, 2800, 2900, 3012, 3230, 
4600), values = c(10, 24, 23, 21, 41, 32, 34)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
   group values
1:  1001     10
2:  2025     24
3:  2800     23
4:  2900     21
5:  3012     41
6:  3230     32
7:  4600     34
```

My desired output:

```
   group values
1:  1001     10
2:  2800     23
3:  3230     32
4:  4600     34
```

How would I go about doing this? It is a large dataset hence the need to use data.table syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your `group_vector` with `%in%` operator.

```
data[group %in% group_vector]

   group values
1:  1001     10
2:  2800     23
3:  3230     32
4:  4600     34
```